# ANTLR4 token only in context

Tags: token, antlr, antlr4

I have follow simple grammar:

```
grammar G;

var : str ('as' str)?;
str : WORD;

WORD : LETTER+;
fragment LETTER : [a-z];
WS : [ ] -> skip;
NEWLINE : [\n] -> skip;
```

I want the word *"as"* to unfold by antlr as `str`rule. For example, the *"as"* string has to be accepted by the parser, but antlr unfold *'as'* as token.

```
line 1:0 missing WORD at 'as'
line 1:2 missing WORD at '<EOF>'
(var (str <missing WORD>) as (str <missing WORD>))
```

How to use antlr so that the word *"as"* is a keyword only in second position?

P.S. The initial problem was to use *"as"* as a keyword only in the import expression and to be able to give variables the name *"as"*.